# What do you call these ways of representing pronunciation?

Tags: word-request

For example:

> 1. Honest **/änəst/**
> 2. Honest **[ahh-nest]**

What are these called?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are asking about IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet)?

Comment: The first one is a phonemic and the second one non-phonemic pronunciation respelling.

Comment: It is phonetic, not phonemic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [*pronunciation respellings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling)—methods of rewriting words so that a reader can tell how they're pronounced. Specifically, /änəst/ looks like an [International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) respelling.

Wikipedia provides a chart showing how various respelling systems map to each other: [Pronunciation respelling for English § Traditional respelling systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English#Traditional_respelling_systems)